# Dynamic heightForHeaderInSection

Tags: header, height, uitableview

How can I modify the height of a header section accordantly to the view I'm adding it?
`heightForHeaderInSection` is called before `viewForHeaderInSection` and I don't know the view size until I create it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can follow this:

1. Create a property for headerView (NSArray if multiple header views).
2. Create the view in "`heightForHeaderInSection`" itself.
3. Assign your view to property.
4. return the height of your view in "`heightForHeaderInSection`".
5. In "viewForHeaderInSection" return this property.

Comment: I forgot to accept this one year ago. This was the solution I have used. The view has nothing to do with labels, so the only solution was to determinate all the views at the beginning, store in an array and then use them in heightForSectionInHeader.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, it seems strange/redundant that you have to create both the view and then also determine the size of that view as a completely separate event, but you can minimize the silliness by moving some of that shared logic into some shared method. E.g., you probably have to figure out the size of the view at some point during it's creation, so move that logic to some shared method.

For example, I have logic that I use for determining the size of the UILabel I'm putting in my header based upon the size of the text. So I pulled that out of my `viewForHeaderInSection` and moved it into my own method, `sizeForHeaderLabelInSection`, which I use to determine the size of my label control):

```
- (CGSize)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sizeForHeaderLabelInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width - kSectionTitleLeftMargin - kSectionTitleRightMargin, kMaxSectionTitleHeight);
    return [text sizeWithFont:[self fontForSectionHeader] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
}
```

Then, I modified the standard `heightForHeaderInSection` to use that method, adding, of course, my top and bottom margin around my UILabel:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
    return [self tableView:tableView sizeForHeaderLabelInSection:section].height + kSectionTitleTopMargin + kSectionTitleBottomMargin;
}
```

And then I modified the standard `viewForHeaderInSection` to also use this `sizeForHeaderLabelInSection`, too:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGSize size = [self tableView:tableView sizeForHeaderLabelInSection:section];

    UIView* headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width + kSectionTitleLeftMargin + kSectionTitleRightMargin, size.height + kSectionTitleTopMargin + kSectionTitleBottomMargin)];
    //headerView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

    // Add the label
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kSectionTitleLeftMargin, 
                                                                     kSectionTitleTopMargin, 
                                                                     size.width, 
                                                                     size.height)];
    // put stuff to set up my headerLabel here...

    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    // Return the headerView
    return headerView;
}
```

Clearly, how you do this is completely up to you and what you're trying to achieve. But I think you'll have success if you shift your mindset from "how do I figure out the size of that view I created in `viewForHeaderInSection`" to "how can I move the the code that I used for determining the size in `viewForHeaderInSection` into some common method that my `heightForSectionInHeader` can use, too.

Answer (score 3):

This also works:

1. Override `estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection`, return a `CGFloat`, whatever, but not 0.
2. Create a `CGFloat` property to save the height for header view.

   ```
   var sectionHeaderViewHeight:CGFloat = 10.0
   ```

   (The value is not important, but never set to `0.0`, if you do this, `viewForHeaderInSection` will never be invoked, you will never have a section header view!)
3. Override `heightForHeaderInSection` and return that property.

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
       return sectionHeaderViewHeight
   }
   ```
4. Create the header view in `viewForHeaderInSection`

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        //configuration your view
        //.....

        return headerView
   }
   ```
5. This is the ***key step***: Add these code before return `headerView`.

   ```
   self.tableView.beginUpdates()
   sectionHeaderViewHeight = //The value you would like to set
   self.tableView.endUpdates()
   ```

### It looks like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
   let headerView = UIView()
   //configuration your view
   //.....
   //----Key Steps:----
   self.tableView.beginUpdates()
   sectionHeaderViewHeight = //The value you would like to set
   self.tableView.endUpdates()
   //----Key Steps----
   return headerView
}

var sectionHeaderViewHeight:CGFloat = 10.0 
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return sectionHeaderViewHeight
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To force calling heightForHeaderInSection method, you just need to call both methods beginUpdates/endUpdates of the UITableView.

First create and init a variable height and return it

```
var height: CGFloat = 160.0

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return height
}
```

Then add a method that will update the section height with a new value

```
func updateHeaderHeight(newHeight: CGFloat) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    height = newHeight
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```